# highlighting text CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to know if is it possible to define various highlight classes in JQuery. What I want to do is highlight some tags selected whith selector1 in orange and other tags selected with selector2 in red.

this is my css code:

```
tag.highlight { background: orange; } //class toggled for tags selected by selector1

tag.highlight_red { background: red; }//class toggled for tags selected by selector2
```

tag.highlight works but tag.highlight_red doesnt. Any idea?

thanks

Comment: The Javascript code would be helpful.

Comment: It would be better if you share which jQuery script you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to change the background color of the element itself or just it's selection color? I guess, define Selection.

If it's just text selection color try the tips here: http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

```
p.red::selection {
    background: #ffb7b7;
}
p.red::-moz-selection {
    background: #ffb7b7;
}
p.blue::selection {
    background: #a8d1ff;
}
p.blue::-moz-selection {
    background: #a8d1ff;
}
p.yellow::selection {
    background: #fff2a8;
}
p.yellow::-moz-selection {
    background: #fff2a8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
tag.highlight { background-color: orange; } //class toggled for tags selected by selector1

tag.highlight_red { background-color: red !important; }//class toggled for tags selected by selector2
```

Comment: This might solve the problem, but you should avoid using `!important`, because it's not good design.